# Export the full descriptions texts of Issues form Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking

I am trying the "export to CSV" function in Gitlab, and I can download all issues into a CSV file. However, I notice that in the section of "description", I can only get the first line of my "description". For example, in my description, if my texts are:

ABC

DEF

Then the "description" contains

ABC

only.

Is there any way that I can download the full of the description text?

Answer (score 0):

After exploring this problem for a while. I notice that if I use API to get the issues information. The problem will be solved!

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

---

1. Download your CSV.
2. Open on Notepad++
3. Run the replace shown on the image.

   *It will remove the newlines inside the comments, and will leave lines starting with numbers first. Replace `\n^[^0-9]` to `; $1`*

4.- Save file and Open it on EXCEL

> It´s made with a regex sustitution, considering issue id as the desired number to be always at the beginning of the line,

---

**The example of the substitution:**
[image]

---

Now you will be able to open it on excel. Watch it after the change.

[image]